# The replaced Fragment layout is not shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have problem in replacing fragments in android.

Both of my fragment layouts are placed in a FrameLayout.

And I have tried replacing two fragment using this code :

```
  Fragment newFragment = new StatisticsFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId(), newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
```

The problem is that after replacing the Fragment, its layout is not shown although its `OncreateView` is called.

Please help me.

EDIT : I put the hole code.

---

I solved my problem by adding background color to my layouts.

---

Answer (score 1):

This is how I replace frameLayouts with fragments:

```
 fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
 Fragment_Main main = new Fragment_Main();

 fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainContainer, main).commit();
```

Try adding `.commit` before ending the statement

Comment: what is R.id.mainContainer ? @kurlicue

Comment: It's the FrameLayout I'm replacing, it's the equivelent to your `((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId()`. But it didn't work?

Comment: Naming your variables like `Fragment_Main` is not such a good practice. Please do read this: https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

Comment: instead of `Fragment newFragment = new StatisticsFragment();` try `StatisticsFragment newFragment = new StatisticsFragment();`. If that doesn't work, try replacing `((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId()` with `R.id.containerID`, "containerID" beeing the ID of the layout you want to replace.

Comment: now I have another problem! the first fragment layout is shown under the second one.

Comment: What is it that you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to change fragment layouts. but now the second layout is displayed over the first one, not replaced!

Comment: You have one initial layout, and two fragments, and you want to replace the initial layout with what? Both of the fragments?

Comment: I solved my problem by adding background color to my layouts.

Comment: You probably fixed the symptom, not the problem, I think you still have two fragments inflated but can only see one, that's not good

Answer (score 0):

This method allows you to load any Fragment to any FrameLayout:

```
/**
 * Function to load a fragment into a inner FrameLayout of auction precap view
 * @param Fragment to load
 * @param If of the container to load fragments to
 */
private void loadInnerFragment(Fragment fragment, int containerId) {
    try {
        FragmentManager childFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction2 = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction2.replace(containerId, fragment);
        transaction2.commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thus, just do:

```
Fragment newFragment = new StatisticsFragment();
        loadInnerFragment(
                newFragment,
                R.id.container
        );
```

Where `R.id.container` is the ID of your FrameLayout

Comment: Could you explain the diffrence please?

Comment: @Kurlicue I am sorry, difference between what? :)

Comment: Your approach and the usual way (without creating a mehod), is it just to catch a possible exception?

Comment: @Kurlicue Oh, it's rather simple. You can put this method in some class (possibly a singleton class) and use it from wherever you want to. Plus, having some functionality in a separate method is a good practice, according to SOLID (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). To sum up: for ease of use :)

Comment: @Kurlicue Not at all! The only afterthought is that if you do put this method into a separate class, be aware of how memory can leak in android. Sometimes it gets fancy and it is easier (in terms of memory) to duplicate this method for each Fragment it is intended to be used in.